# Source code of a real time application

Tags: c, real-time

I am working on a project to develop a Scheduler Framework for Real Time Systems . I need the source code of a sample realtime application in C language to test my framework . The application is expected to submit periodic tasks with soft deadlines .

Comment: you should look into ecos real time operating system. http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs.html

Comment: ... or http://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/FreeRTOS/Source/

Comment: real-time application is just a usual application, what makes it real-time is the real-time scheduler. specifically in linux you may specify the application as realtime, interactive or batch

Comment: I need the source code to know about the nature of a sample real-time task and its timing properties like relative deadline , worst case execution time , period etc .

Comment: @truly_geek in case of periodic task, why don't you just use some loop inside of `main()` with some statements inside, and calculate its execution time by means of timer ?

Answer (score 0):

you should look into ecos real time operating system. 
http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs.html